# Errors No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I have a problem when I try to get data using @GET retrofit from the server, the following error occurs: No adapter attached; skipping layout

MainActivity

```
package com.example.restart

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.example.restart.api.ApiRequest
import com.example.restart.api.CatalogAdapter
import com.example.restart.api.CatalogModel
import com.example.restart.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.awaitResponse
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private var adapterCatalog = CatalogAdapter()
    lateinit var catalogList: ArrayList<CatalogModel>


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding!!.root)
        getData()
    }
    private lateinit var allblock: List<CatalogModel>

    private fun initCategory(category: List<CatalogModel>) {
        with(binding!!){
            listCatalogInMain.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, 1)
            listCatalogInMain.adapter = adapterCatalog
            var cataloglist: List<CatalogModel> = category
            if(cataloglist.isNotEmpty()){
                for(element in cataloglist){
                    adapterCatalog.addCatalog(element)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getData(){
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://medic.madskill.ru")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiRequest::class.java)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                val response = api.getCatalog().awaitResponse()
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val data = response.body()!!
                    catalogList = data as ArrayList<CatalogModel>
                    runOnUiThread { initCategory(catalogList) }
                    Log.d(TAG, data.toString())
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ApiRequest

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface ApiRequest {
    @GET("/api/catalog")
    fun getCatalog(): Call<List<CatalogModel>>
}
```

Adapter

```
package com.example.restart.api

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.restart.R
import com.example.restart.databinding.ItemBlockBinding

class CatalogAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CatalogAdapter.CategoryHolder>() {
    private val listCatalog = ArrayList<CatalogModel>()

    class CategoryHolder(item: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item){
        private var bindingCategory = ItemBlockBinding.bind(item)

        fun bind(category: CatalogModel){
            bindingCategory.name.text = category.name
            bindingCategory.category.text = category.category
            bindingCategory.bio.text = category.bio
            bindingCategory.price.text = category.price
            bindingCategory.timeResult.text = category.time_result
            bindingCategory.preparation.text = category.preparation
            bindingCategory.description.text = category.description
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_block, parent, false)
        return CategoryHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listCatalog.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(listCatalog[position])
    }

    fun addCatalog(category: CatalogModel){
        listCatalog.add(category)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

The Internet is conducted, the RecyclerView alignment is wrap_content, do you have any ideas what the problem might be?

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listCatalogInMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_block">
            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    .....
    .....
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Internet is conducted, the RecyclerView alignment is wrap_content, do you have any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Is it actually failing to display? You'll always see that warning in your logs because you're not actually setting an adapter on your RecyclerView until `initCategory` is called. So when the view hierarchy is first laid out, the RV can't be handled since it has no adapter. Usually you just set the LayoutManager and Adapter once at startup (e.g. in `onCreate`, `onViewCreated` etc) and then just pass new data to your adapter when you need to change what's displayed, and let the adapter handle updating itself

Answer (score 0):

i checked this, looks fine for me.
I also tried to reproduce from my side. It's working at my end.
I used this as item_block.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="A" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/category"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="A" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="A" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="A" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="A" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/preparation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="A" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="A" />
```